# Vert.x Service Proxies: Just after I change service methods from returning Future<T> to Uni<T> of Smallrye Mutiny, the code generation failed

Tags: vert.x, mutiny

I've sucessfully generated service proxies for service having methods returning `Future<T>`, 
but just after I changed those methods to return `Uni<T>` according to [API Translation - Smallrye Mutiny Vert.x bindings](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny-vertx-bindings/2.30.1/api-translation/), 
when I try to execute `mvn clean compile` it always tells me this error message :

> Could not generate model for com.example.beers.BarmanService#giveMeAStaticBeer(java.lang.String): Proxy methods must have void or Fluent returns

I would need your help to enlighten me how to fix it.

I put those codes on [GitHub](https://github.com/cyclops0079/starter-service-proxy-mutiny-bak/commit/724dc797cbcf07beea6a2e11e0a3d3915fb1c7a8), and these are some critical ones:

```
//BarmanService.java

@VertxGen
@ProxyGen
public interface BarmanService {

    Uni<Beer> giveMeAStaticBeer(String customerName);
    Uni<Integer> getMyBill(String customerName);
    Uni<Void> payMyBill(String customerName);

    static BarmanService createProxy(Vertx vertx, String address) {
        return new BarmanServiceVertxEBProxy(vertx, address);
    }

}
```

```
//BarmanServiceImpl.java

public class BarmanServiceImpl implements BarmanService {

    Map<String, Integer> bills;

    public BarmanServiceImpl() {
        this.bills = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Uni<Beer> giveMeAStaticBeer(String customerName) {
        Beer beer = new Beer("Workshop River Stout", "English Stout", 5);
        return Uni.createFrom().item(() -> beer);
    }

    @Override
    public Uni<Integer> getMyBill(String customerName) {
        return Uni.createFrom().item(() -> bills.get(customerName));
    }

    @Override
    public Uni<Void> payMyBill(String customerName) {
        bills.remove(customerName);
        System.out.println("Removed debt of " + customerName);
        return Uni.createFrom().voidItem();
    }
}
```

```
//package-info.java

@ModuleGen(groupPackage = "com.example", name = "beers")
package com.example.beers;

import io.vertx.codegen.annotations.ModuleGen;
```

```
<!-- //pom.xml -->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- // ... -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-codegen</artifactId>
            <classifier>processor</classifier>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-service-proxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- // ... -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.smallrye.reactive</groupId>
            <artifactId>smallrye-mutiny-vertx-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.30.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.smallrye.reactive</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-mutiny-generator</artifactId>
            <version>2.30.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- // ... -->
    </dependencies>
```

PS In the beginning, when I generated service proxies for service having methods returning `Future<T>`, there is a [generated class](https://github.com/cyclops0079/starter-service-proxy-mutiny-bak/blob/0234fd8f1cb3ef3bb5a5531d08209bd3a947e667/target/generate-soures/annotations/com/example/mutiny/beers/BarmanService.java) returning `Uni<T>`, but I have no idea how to use it:

```
package com.example.mutiny.beers;

@io.smallrye.mutiny.vertx.MutinyGen(com.example.beers.BarmanService.class)
public class BarmanService {

  public static final io.smallrye.mutiny.vertx.TypeArg<BarmanService> __TYPE_ARG = new io.smallrye.mutiny.vertx.TypeArg<>(    obj -> new BarmanService((com.example.beers.BarmanService) obj),
    BarmanService::getDelegate
  );

  private final com.example.beers.BarmanService delegate;
  
  public BarmanService(com.example.beers.BarmanService delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }

  public BarmanService(Object delegate) {
    this.delegate = (com.example.beers.BarmanService)delegate;
  }

  /**
   * Empty constructor used by CDI, do not use this constructor directly.
   **/
  BarmanService() {
    this.delegate = null;
  }

  public com.example.beers.BarmanService getDelegate() {
    return delegate;
  }

  @CheckReturnValue
  public io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni<com.example.beers.Beer> giveMeAStaticBeer(String customerName) { 
    return io.smallrye.mutiny.vertx.UniHelper.toUni(delegate.giveMeAStaticBeer(customerName));}

  public com.example.beers.Beer giveMeAStaticBeerAndAwait(String customerName) { 
    return giveMeAStaticBeer(customerName).await().indefinitely();
  }


  public void giveMeAStaticBeerAndForget(String customerName) { 
    giveMeAStaticBeer(customerName).subscribe().with(io.smallrye.mutiny.vertx.UniHelper.NOOP);
  }

  // ...

  public static com.example.mutiny.beers.BarmanService createProxy(io.vertx.mutiny.core.Vertx vertx, String address) { 
    com.example.mutiny.beers.BarmanService ret = com.example.mutiny.beers.BarmanService.newInstance((com.example.beers.BarmanService)com.example.beers.BarmanService.createProxy(vertx.getDelegate(), address));
    return ret;
  }

  public static  BarmanService newInstance(com.example.beers.BarmanService arg) {
    return arg != null ? new BarmanService(arg) : null;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out by myself. About to change service methods from returning `Future<T>` to `Uni<T>`

[The wrong apporach](https://github.com/cyclops0079/starter-service-proxy-mutiny-bak/commit/724dc797cbcf07beea6a2e11e0a3d3915fb1c7a8) I did:

1. Edit package-info to remove `useFutures = true`
2. Edit service interfaces and change returning types
3. Edit service implementations and change returning types, also change logic
4. Edit verticles to handle `Uni<T>` returned from service

And it turned out that the first three steps I did is unnecessary,

[the suitable approach](https://github.com/cyclops0079/starter-service-proxy-mutiny-bak/commit/f1d356820d3ae3ed7c5847bc2e8f33ae75867409) is:

1. Wrap vertx:

```
io.vertx.mutiny.core.Vertx mutinyVertx = new io.vertx.mutiny.core.Vertx(vertx);
```

2. Change the use of service interface to the generated one

```
import com.example.mutiny.beers.BarmanService;
```

3. Use the wrapped vertx:

```
BarmanService barmanService = BarmanService.createProxy(mutinyVertx, "beers.services.myapplication");
```

4. Edit verticles to handle `Uni<T>` returned from service

My problem has been solved, but I am not sure is it a good approach to manually wrap the vertx on the `MainVerticle` launched by io.vertx.core.Launcher:

```
io.vertx.mutiny.core.Vertx mutinyVertx = new io.vertx.mutiny.core.Vertx(vertx);
```

Any suggestions guys?

Comment: If your verticle extends `io.smallrye.mutiny.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle` you don't have to wrap the Vert.x yourself.